# Was Isaac Newton responsible for the loss of Robert Hooke's work?

Tags: history, art, scientific-papers

[This Yahoo answer](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100516224919AAqgR5K) citing [this dead source](http://www.scienceandyou.org/articles/ess_14.shtml) ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20080115124111/http://www.scienceandyou.org/articles/ess_14.shtml)) claims:

> It may be a coincidence but the only known portrait of Hooke which had
>   been housed in the President's office, was mysteriously lost as were
>   the records of much of Hooke's work. In Newton's defense it could be
>   argued that the lack of acknowledgment for Robert Hooke and his
>   contribution to science could be blamed on Hooke himself.

[This page](http://www.cs4fn.org/alife/hooked.html) even claims:

> His feud with Issac Newton meant that when Newton took over as the
>   President of the Royal Society he destroyed all the pictures of Hooke.
>   However The Royal Society have kindly provided us with picture of some
>   of the remaining sketches of Hooke to include in this page.

Was any of Hooke's works lost, and was Isaac Newton responsible for the loss?

Comment: Here's a snapshot of the dead source from January 15, 2008: http://web.archive.org/web/20080115124111/http://www.scienceandyou.org/articles/ess_14.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other sources only mention the portrait, but answers to [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/357/did-isaac-newton-burn-robert-hookes-picture) question whether a portrait of Hooke even existed.

As does the [Royal Society](http://blogs.royalsociety.org/history-of-science/2010/12/03/hooke-newton-missing-portrait/) itself, despite quoting a visitor that mentioned Hooke's portrait. The visitor might have meant the portrait of Theodore Haak:

> But before we pronounce Newton guilty of destroying Royal Society
>   property, we need to consider the fundamental question of whether a
>   portrait of Hooke existed in the first place. **None of the evidence on
>   this point is really conclusive.** There are two pieces of evidence to
>   suggest there was a portrait. The first comes from Hooke’s diary, or
>   memorandum book, in which he recorded his daily life in some detail
>   for long periods from the 1670s to 1690s. In an entry for 16 October
>   1674 he wrote ‘At Garaways. Left off taking tobacco — Mr Bonust drew
>   picture.’ Garaways was a coffee-house much visited by Hooke, but ‘Mr
>   Bonust’ is a rather mysterious figure who only appears once in the
>   diary. The first editors of the diary suggested that this was one
>   ‘Bownest’, whose portrait of ejected minister Arthur Jacksonis housed
>   in the National Portrait Gallery in the form of an engraving by David
>   Loggan. Hooke was interested in art, and visited various painters,
>   including Mary Beale, who painted his friend and colleague Robert
>   Boyle, and the miniaturist Mary Moore, mother of Hooke’s friend
>   Richard Waller(himself an accomplished artist). However if Mr Bownest
>   did draw Hooke’s picture in 1674, this is the only reference Hooke
>   made to it.
>
> The second piece of evidence is a description of a visit to the Royal
>   Society’s premises in 1710 by a German traveller, Zacharias Conrad von
>   Uffenbach. Like many other scientifically-minded travellers of the
>   day, von Uffenbach was keen to see the famous Royal Society – but the
>   reality was a severe disappointment for him. After being shown the
>   Repository and meeting rooms at Gresham College, he wrote dismissively
>   in his travel-journal,
>
> “the finest instruments and other articles [lie] . . . not only in no
>   sort of order or tidiness but covered with dust, filth and coal-smoke,
>   and many of them broken and utterly ruined. If one inquires after
>   anything, the operator who shows strangers round . . . will usually
>   say: ‘A rogue had it stolen away’, or he will show you pieces of it,
>   saying: ‘It is corrupted or broken’; and such is the care they take of
>   things! . . . Finally we were shown the room where the Society usually
>   meets. It is very small and wretched and the best things there are the
>   portraits of its members, of which the most noteworthy are those of
>   Boyle and Hoock.”
>
> Von Uffenbach, a foreign visitor briefly shown the Society’s meeting
>   room, is the only person to make such a reference to Hooke’s portrait.
>   James Yonge, who visited the Society in November 1702 and was elected
>   FRS at the time, recorded seeing ‘divers original pictures’ in the
>   Council Room. He listed eleven portraits, including those of Robert
>   Boyle and Theodore Haak, but Hooke’s was not among them. It seems
>   unlikely that Yonge would have overlooked Hooke’s picture if it was
>   there. Hooke was Yonge’s first contact at the Society: the two men had
>   corresponded for many years and Yonge referred to Hooke in his journal
>   as ‘my old friend’.
>
> Other sources in which we might expect to find a mention of Hooke’s
>   portrait are curiously silent on the subject. The inventory of Hooke’s
>   possessions after his death does not include a portrait. Richard
>   Waller, who wrote the first biography of Hooke in the preface to his
>   edition of Hooke’s papers, printed two years after Hooke’s death,
>   never mentioned a portrait. Neither did Hooke’s second posthumous
>   editor, William Derham. And if a portrait did exist, there is no
>   evidence that it was given to the Royal Society. The minutes of the
>   Society’s meetings, in which gifts such as portraits were often (but
>   not always!) recorded, say nothing about a portrait of Hooke, and
>   neither do any other lists of donations in the period. Hooke himself,
>   who was very protective of his scientific reputation and prestige,
>   never spoke of donating his own portrait to the Society.
>
> The absence of any corroborating evidence must cast some doubt on von
>   Uffenbach’s claim to have seen a portrait of Hooke at Gresham
>   Collegein 1710. Was he shown Theodore Haak’s portrait and misheard the
>   name? Hooke was the more famous Fellow and von Uffenbach may have
>   assumed the Society had his portrait. I think we can say that although
>   Hooke may have had his picture taken, it is unlikely to have been
>   hanging in the Society’s meeting room at Gresham College. **And Newton?
>   He’s definitely off the hook.**

...despite stating earlier that none of the evidence is conclusive, the Royal Society concludes with a definite. Also lending credence to Uffenbach's claim that property was lost (presumably including sketches), is that the article links to Theodore Haak are dead.

Comment: Or off the Hooke!